# Listbox DisplayValue for Newtonsoft JToken

Tags: c#, winforms, json.net, listbox

I have a List (from Newtonsoft), and I'm trying to define a DisplayValue for Microsoft .NET list box.

```
List<JToken> gCollectionRequests = new List<JToken>();
//Code here to create a valid gCollectionRequests
listBox1.DataSource = gCollectionRequests;
listBox1.DisplayMember = gCollectionRequests[0]["name"].Value<string>();
```

The List is based on a JSON Postman collection file, whose first field is "name". That's what I want to display. The line line above doesn't break the code, it just doesn't have any effect.

An example of the gCollectionRequests:
[image]

What is the right way to define the DisplayValue from List source?

Comment: Can you update your post to include a simple example including your json so we can further help you?

Comment: @zaggler Example added.

Comment: Please add code if possible, not just images.

Comment: For `DisplayMember` to work, you need to provide a property name. But, JToken obviously doesn't have a property `name`. You need your own type with the required property to bind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @SriramSakthivel. That was the key. So I made a new object that incorporated my JSON collection. Is this how you would have done it?

```
public class CombinedJTokens
{
    private int RequestCount; //Not really needed.
    public JToken MyRequest;

    public CombinedJTokens(int myCount, JToken myToken)
    {
        this.RequestCount = myCount;
        this.MyRequest = myToken;
    }

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return string.Format("This is a JToken: {0}", MyRequest["name"].Value<string>()); }
    }
}
```

Then, this handles filling in the listbox:

```
private void FillInListBoxWithRequests()
{
     List<CombinedJTokens> myCombinedTokensList = new List<CombinedJTokens>();
     int theCount = 0;
     foreach (var item in gCollectionRequests)
     {
          JToken myNewJToken = item;
          CombinedJTokens myCombinedJTokens = new CombinedJTokens(++theCount, item);
          myCombinedTokensList.Add(myCombinedJTokens);
     }
     listBox1.DataSource = null;
     listBox1.DataSource = myCombinedTokensList;
     listBox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
}
```

gCollectionRequests is a list of the JSON requests defined as:

```
List<JToken> gCollectionRequests = new List<JToken>();
```